# Correct method of BETWEEN in SQL

Tags: sql, between

What is the correct method of using between, because treehouse and my teacher have different answers for this question.

Select all movies from the years 1999 to 2004.

Treehouse answer:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year BETWEEN 1999 AND 2004;
```

Teachers answer:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year >= 1999 AND year <= 2004;
```

Which method is correct?

Comment: Both sources are right.  These two queries will produce the identical result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are technically correct.  However, there are reasons to avoid using `between` as your teacher suggests.  The simplest is that in English, the word is ambiguous and can include the end points or not.  In fact, if you say that a point on a line is between two other points, the meaning is generally that the point does not coincide either end point.

This is a minor issue for integers.  It becomes much more important with other data types.  A particular issue is with date times.  If you have a datetime field in the database, then the following does not work the way you expect:

```
where datetimefield between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-02'
```

This will return all datetime values from 2013-01-01.  Plus, it will return a datetime value that is at exactly midnight between the two dates.  It will not return any other value from 2013-01-02.

I am heartened that your teacher recognizes the shortcomings of `between`.  I hope s/he also explains why the explicit comparison method is better.

EDIT:

By the way, something similar happens for strings as well.  So:

```
where charfield between 'a' and 'b'
```

will return all values that start with 'a' and exactly 'b'.  But not 'ba' or 'b1'.  One way to write it is:

```
where charfield >= 'a' and charfield < 'c'
```

The point is.  `between` is a perfectly valid SQL construct.  It works "correctly" for all data types.  However, what is correct for SQL may not be intuitive for most people.  Explicit comparisons come closer to avoiding this problem.

Comment: Isn't using `between` with *only* a date-part guaranteed to give rise to bugs anyway, when being used on a datetime field?

Comment: @skiwi . . . If you use a correct form such as `dt >= '2013-01-01' and dt < '2013-01-03'` then there is no problem.  If you are in the habit of using `between, you might use it and have this issue.

Comment: @AdzTi . . . I would encourage you to understand how `between` really works.  Don't use it for strings and dates.  In my opinion, using it for integers is ok.  The key is to be alert in code you write (or other people write) for possible errors.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the comment, "Are they the only 2 methods? Or is their alot more? "  Here are a few other ways to do it.

```
 where year in (1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
 where year > 1998 and year < 2005
```

as suggested in Gordon's answer

```
where date >= {d '1999-01-01'} and date < {d '2005-01-01'}
```

All the answers are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`BETWEEN` is just for the developers! The optimizer underneath still uses `>=` and `<=` anyways when it recognises a `BETWEEN` clause.
I would prefer `BETWEEN` is the best approach! Reason , it gives good readability.